# Skip FETCHSOURCE step in Google Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-build

I've set up a google cloud build trigger which should execute when I push to a repo. The repository that is sent to the workerPool is incorrect, because it should be using a proxy url to be accessible from the workerPool. When the build is triggered, it fails, because the FETCHSOURCE step at the beginning uses that incorrect "non-proxied" URL. Is there any method to skip or disable the initial attempt Cloud Build makes to clone the repo?

I initially thought this might be a step in the prebuilt cloud-builder images. However, using a vanilla ubuntu image as the first step doesn't seem to bipass the FETCHSOURCE step. I also tried using a substitution variable for _REPO_URL, but that didn't overwrite the repo url on the fetchsource step.

Comment: The initial `FETCHSOURCE` step in Google Cloud Build is a crucial stage in the build process and cannot be skipped or disabled. Cloning the repository and making it accessible to the following build steps is the responsibility of the `FETCHSOURCE` phase. You may file a [feature request](http://issuetracker.google.com) for this concern and the Product Team will check if this concern is valid. However, there's no ETA for it.

Comment: At the very best this is a bug. Fetch source shouldn't abide by the repo URL from the push payload in one instance and use the host connection in manual triggers. It should just the host connection in all cases.